# New request created with php artisan, always returns invalid response in ajax in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, validation, request

I've created a new request with php artisan command. When I send my form to be validated with laravel built-in request in ajax, it will return the response of validation correctly, however when I send it and want to validate it with the new request created with php artisan earlier, it returns all inputs invalid, but if I set the rules in an array in the controller and use it there, it works correctly.

```
public function postIndex(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->get('form');
    parse_str($data, $data);
    // it works and return validation correctly
    $rules = [some rules here];
    $validity = Validator::make($data, $rules);
}

public function postIndex(newRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->get('form');
    parse_str($data, $data);
    // but this one returns all validations messages even if they are or not valid!!!
    $validity = Validator::make($data);
}
```

How can I fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Share your controller method code along with the form code.

Comment: `$data` is undefined in your code. You shouldn't be validating in the controller if you're using a FormRequest with validation rules.

Comment: As you can see I haven't written codes completely, but only the ones needed. $data are the data got from html form.

Comment: This is why we need to see your code. `$data = $request->get('form');` will get the value of a single form field with `name="form"`. If you want `$data` to be all the fields you need `$request->all()`.

Comment: I want to use ajax and the event is on click, how can I get fields with $request->all??

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `$data` is not defined on your code and you don't need to call `Validator` when you are validating with a custom created Request, so your method just needs to be

```
public function postIndex(newRequest $request)
{
  //Do whatever here
}
```

And just catch the errors on your ajax callback

```
error: function(data){
    var errors = data.responseJSON;
    console.log(errors);
  }
```

Comment: As you can see I haven't written codes completely, but only the ones needed. $data are the data got from html form.

Comment: Well, even if you didn't put the source of the `$data` variable on your example, this line: `$validity = Validator::make($data);` is not necessary.

Comment: Edited. Now what's the problem?

Comment: Look, when you validate with a custom Request you create, you don't need to call `Validator`. When you do this `newRequest $request`, the validation already is being executed considering `newRequest` is your own created Request, so this stuff:

`$data = $request->get('form');
    parse_str($data, $data);
    $validity = Validator::make($data);`

Is unnecessary...

Comment: Exactly this is the problem, if I want to use from the request created earlier, it doesn't validate the fields sent. So how can I get if the validity fails or passes?!

Comment: If the created request isn't working, then something is wrong with it, could you post your request class?

Comment: class newRequest extends Request { public function authorize(){ return true; } }

Comment: public function rules() { return [ 'username' => 'required' ]; }  and so on.

Comment: Be sure the `authorize` function inside your request returns true.

Comment: Yes it returns true as I said in previous comment.

Comment: Then do a `dd($request->all())` inside your controller method and tell us or check if your input is correct.

Comment: All of the inputs are correct, if they weren't, it wouldn't return correct validation with Request type-hint. My guess is that the form because is serialized first and when sent to controller, the fields are validated first and return the validation result in real-time, note that the data are string at first and after parse_str changes to array.